# How to enable "Reinforced.Typings" in the configuration?

Tags: c#, .net, reinforced-typings

Rebuilding the project does not run Reinforced typings. It says in Output:

```
warning : Reinforced.Typings will not run because it is disabled in its configuration
```

I tried making a completely clean and new project, but the same thing happened.
It does not seem to be an error in the xml or Configuration files to me.

How do you enable it?

Comment: welcome - please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Usually RT is being disabled by `<RtDisable>` parameter set to `true` (actually any value that differs from 'false'). Please double-check it.

Also please check that there is reference to `Reinforced.Typings.targets` from your `.csproj` file (it must be added automatically by NuGet).

Comment: <RtDisable> is set to false. And I forgot to mention I'm using .NetCore 3. There's is no reference to Reinforced.Typings.targets in .csproj. I tried reinstalling the NuGut.